# Receiving badges very long after meeting the criteria

Tags: feature-request, bug, badges, electorate-badge

Recently, I completed the "electorate" badge.  I voted 600 times on questions, but did not receive my badge immediately.  It was only after 10 minutes that I got it.  Is this a bug?  Or else could it be corrected?